# Load functions backbone in external file Error

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

this is a very noob problem, sorry but not find that =/.

I make my backbone functions in index.html, inside the `<script>` tag.

But i want move this code backbone to external file how `functions-backbone.js`, what i can make to this works ?

I move the code, some ctrc+ctrv and receive this error from console:
`"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token %= "`

I put the Jquery initializer around but same error, someone can help me ? Thanks much.

Comment: You probably using underscorejs for templating. Move only js and not your html templates.

Comment: The html is embed in backbone: `my_template: _.template("<a href='?user=<%%= phone %>'><strong><%%= name %></strong> (<%%= phone %>)"),`

Comment: where exactly you get the exception? in html or js file?

Answer (score 0):

Your  syntax for template is wrong, I think. Isn't it

```
_.template("<a href='?user=<%= phone %>'><strong><%= name %></strong> (<%= phone %>)")
```

Comment: yeah, if he uses default settings then you are right :)

Comment: I using Rails, becaause this need use <%%, i will use Rails 4.0 now and the gem backbone-rails, is integrated, but thanks all by the help.